# Every event fires when I click a button in with this JQuery code

Tags: jquery

I have 30 or so a buttons followed by a `div` that holds the content. The problem is that they all fire when I click any a button. I would like the function to only run on the button clicked and its corresponding `div`. I assume I'll need `this` and `next` but I'm not sure how to go about it.

```
 $(function(){
    $('.button').click(toggleBox);
 });

 function toggleBox(){

   var box = $('.content');

   if (box.data('on') == true){
       boxOff();
       } else { // box's on property is false (it's off), so we need to turn it on
       boxOn();
       }
  }

  function boxOn(){ //function removes open button and shows content
      $('.button').removeClass('open-button').addClass('closed-button');
      $('.content').removeClass('closed-content').addClass('open-content').data("on",true);
       }

  function boxOff(){ //function removes close button and hides content
      $('.button').removeClass('closed-button').addClass('open-button');
      $('.content').removeClass('open-content').addClass('closed-content').data("on",false);
                    }
```

Comment: add `id=""` to your buttons or find a better way to specify them. EI `$('.button').first().click(function(){ });`

Comment: You should post a jsFiddle or post your HTML here.

Comment: @JoeFletch The HTML is preferred. JSfiddle is discouraged because questions and answers should stand on their own, without external links.  External links die.

Comment: @Nick I'd like to stay away from IDs since I'll be using this 30 different times.

Comment: @JoeFletch Here is the jsFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Bbz53/)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, true, I will keep that in mind when asking for it in the future. Normally when I answer a question, I do both (jsFiddle and posting code here in the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is not working as expected is your use of classes. The follwing line in your function `var box = $('.content');` grabs ALL elements with that class, and from your question i suppose you only want a specific one. If You present more HTML i can show you an exact answer but for now:

If your HTML looks like this:

```
<button class="open-button">Click Me</button>
<div class="close-content" data-on="false">Content in here</div>
```

Then your script would be something like this:

```
$('.button').on("click", function(e) {
    if ($(this).next(".content").data("on")) {
        $(this).removeClass("open-button").addClass("close-button")
            .next(".content").removeClass("close-content").addClass("open-content").data("on",true);
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass("close-button").addClass("open-button")
            .next(".content").removeClass("open-content").addClass("close-content").data("on",false);
    };
});
```

Comment: Had some oops line mistakes, fixed em

Comment: Awfully close. Thanks. They open fine but they don't close. Here is a the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/xTz8W/)

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess since I'm not positive as to your set-up, but it sounds like something I had to do recently.  Also, from the sound of it, we're probably about on the same jQuery level, so be easy on me.

Does this work for you?

```
function boxOn(){ //function removes open button and shows content
  $(this).removeClass('open-button').addClass('closed-button').next('.content').removeClass('closed-content').addClass('open-content').data("on",true);
   }

function boxOff(){ //function removes close button and hides content
  $(this).removeClass('closed-button').addClass('open-button').next('.content').removeClass('open-content').addClass('closed-content').data("on",false);
                    }
```

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to work. There aren't any glaring errors or anything - its just not firing. Thanks for giving it a go.

Comment: @SpYk3HH answered it better.  If [link](http://www.wethetrees.com/faq) is at all similar to what you're trying to do, let me know and I can send you the code- it's only 6 lines.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You may use  "`button:nth-child()`" Selector to refer them.

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/